# Did all stories in "The Fountain" happen?

Tags: the-fountain

Did all three stories in *The Fountain* (2006) happen?  The "present" story, with the doctor and his dying wife presumably happened, that's not in question.  But what about the "past" timeline, with the conquistador and the search for the Fountain of Youth?  Is that just a visualization of Izzie's story that she was writing?

And what about the "future" timeline, with the astronaut who is presumably the doctor? Is this really happening?

There are links between the three.  When the conquistador finds the Ziggurat with the Tree of a Life, we see the astronaut from the future, who helps him pass to the garden.  At the end of the present timeline, a tree is planted that seems to be the tree in the space bubble, and the doctor's discovery of a cure for all disease seems to be what is keeping the astronaut alive.

Are they all happening?